# parallelization issue using python view library

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython, ipython-parallel

so i Worte some code with basic structure like this:

```
from numpy import *
from dataloader import loadfile
from IPython.parallel import Client
from clustering import * 

data = loadfile(0)

N_CLASSES = 10
rowmax = nanmax(data.values, 0)
rowmin = nanmin(data.values, 0)

# Defines the size of block processed at a time
BLOCK_SIZE = 50000
classmean, classcov, classcovinv, classlogdet, classlogprob = init_stats(data, N_CLASSES, rowmax, rowmin)

client = Client()
ids    = client.ids
nodes  = len(ids)
view   = client.load_balanced_view()
dview  = client[:]

def get_ml_class(data, args): do sth
dview.scatter('datablock', data)
dview.execute('res1, res2 = get_ml_class(datablock, args)', block=False)
```

the output of dview.execute part is

```
<AsyncResult: execute>
```

which means it is executed, however, when i was trying to pull the result by

```
dview.pull(['res1','res2'], block=True)
```

it shows:

```
NameError: name 'res1' is not defined
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us make a simpler example:

```
from IPython.parallel import Client

rc = Client()
dview = rc[:]
dview.scatter('a', Range(16))
dview.execute('res1,res2 = a[0], a[1]', block=False)
dview.pull(['res1'], block=True)
```

This works as expected and gives a the result:

```
[[0], [4], [8], [12]]
```

So, we do at least this one right. But let me change the code a bit:

```
from IPython.parallel import Client

rc = Client()
dview = rc[:]
dview.scatter('a', Range(16))
dview.execute('res1,res2 = a[0], b[1]', block=False)
dview.pull(['res1'], block=True)
```

Now we have the `NameError`. Why?

Because there is an error on the `execute` line (it references to variable `b` which does not exist). The non-blocking `execute` does not complain much. In the first (working) case the status is:

```
<AsyncResult: finished>
```

and in the second (non-working) case:

```
<AsyncResult: execute>
```

Other than that it is very quiet, and the second message does not necessarily mean an error has occured. In order to see the real error message, change `blocking` to  `True`. Then you'll see what is going wrong.

If you want to know if your non-blocking execute works, you have to capture the `AsyncResult` object returned by `execute`. It has several interesting methods, but you would be most interested in `ready` and `successful` methods:

```
ar = dview.execute(...)
ar.ready()                # True if the process has finished
ar.successful()           # True if there were no exceptions raised
```

Also, the possible exceptions raised during the execution can be fetched by using the `get` method of the `AsyncResult` object. For example my bad example gives in the interactive shell:

```
>>> ar.get()

[0:execute]: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-1-608f57d70b2f> in <module>()
----> 1 res1,res2=a[0]**2,b[1]**2
NameError: name 'b' is not defined

[1:execute]: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-1-608f57d70b2f> in <module>()
----> 1 res1,res2=a[0]**2,b[1]**2
NameError: name 'b' is not defined

...
```

So, as a summary: Try to find out what goes wrong with the function you try to run remotely. Now it seems to raise some execption. The error might have something to do with `args` which does not seem to be available for the remote scripts. Maybe a `scatter` is missing?

Comment: thanks for the reply but what's the difference between ur 1st and 2nd code??

Comment: Ahh, the second one contains an error (references to an unknown variable). See my edited answer.